# email button with copy and chevron.. NO DIVS

Tags: html, css, button, html-email

I am trying to create a button without using divs, as it's a button for an email template. I am definitely getting mad as I am not able to achieve my design.

What I am trying to do is something very simple, like this:
[image]

The text "Button" may be longer and changing dynamically, therefore the text should be able to break lines and the chevron (>) should be always vertically centered.

I have tried to create two span tags, one for the text and one for the chevron but I am not able to use the space in a good way because of the span (cannot define width and they are not staying next to each other)

I have tried to use ::after on the span, and I am currently playing with that, but I am not able to center vertically this holy chevron if the text is 1-2-3 lines long.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fd4k91ra/)

```
<a href="#" class="button">
  <span>TEST BUTTON</span>
</a>


.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 220px;
  min-height: 41px;
  background-color: #c9ec6b;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 10px;
}

.button::after {
  content: ">";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 14px;
  top: 50%;
}
```

any ideas? I am driving crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML email is basically stuck in the 90s because of the clients you need to be able to support. (For example, Outlook uses the engine in MS Word to render HTML, which is nuts.) Since that's the case, your best bet in HTML email is to use tables, and not only that, but tables within tables.

It sounds awful, and it is, but it's the reality of HTML email.

The other thing is that you can't rely on stylesheets. Even Gmail will reject your entire head, so whatever you put there will essentially disappear.

You need to try to achieve this with a combination of old-fashioned table layout (which can be made responsive by inlining CSS like `max-width`) and inline CSS. You can write your CSS separately, but you should then use an inlining tool, like the one [provided by Mailchimp](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/).

You might end up with something like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" style="display: block; text-decoration: none; color: black; font-size: 32px;">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr style="border: 3px solid black;">
        <td style="padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 20px; 
                   padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 20px;">Button
        </td>
        <td style="padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 20px; 
                   padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 20px;">>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</a>
```

Weird, but that's HTML email for you.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best solution as the use of tables for the button would simplify a lot the code and most probably also the support of the mail clients. I didn't know it was possible to put an anchor on a whole table anyway, I hope this is supported :-)

Comment: Hi Marco. I should add that I didn't test the code and is somewhat incomplete. You usually want to set cellspacing=0, cellpadding=0, border=0 on tables in HTML email.

Comment: Sure, not a problem, I have already tested it and added everything needed :-) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this `transform: translate(0, -50%);`

```
.button::after {
    content: ">";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 14px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution works perfectly, I am just wondering if the transform property is supported by email clients then..!